# Ensure object properties passed through function equal certain values?

Tags: javascript

I have a class which uses certain properties throughout methods.

```
function MyClass(elementSelectors) {
    this.elements = {};
    for (var elementSelector in elementSelectors) {
        this.elements[elementSelector] = document.querySelector(elementSelector);
    }
}

myClass.prototype.usesAnElement = function () {
    console.log(this.elements['header']);
};

var elementSelectors = {
    headr: '[class="header"]' // this is sort of an error?
}
var myClass = new MyClass();
```

Now I'm thinking of future errors. What if someone accidentally misspells a property. I'm wondering if there was a secret way  of requiring only certain properties (other than checking them in a separate array containing the possibilities).

Comment: There is no secret way. You have to test explicitly whether a desired property exists or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test the property against a map of available ones and only attempt to use it if it's valid

```
//available properties
avail = {
    "header": true,  //or anything that evaluates to true
    "foo": true,
    "bar": true
}

//test if a property is valid before trying to do something with it
if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(avail, elementSelector)) {
    this.elements[elementSelector] = document.querySelector(elementSelectors[elementSelector]);    
}
```

**Edit**
Or, if you don't care for IE8 support, or don't mind adding a polyfill for `indexOf` you can use arrays (solution suggested below).

Comment: I broke your code: `elementSelector = "toString"`; It would be better to try `["header", "foo", "bar"].indexOf(elementSelector) != -1` or `avail.hasOwnProperty(elementSelector)`

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll settle with just checking them.